# What's the correct approach for having a list/detail view with React Native Navigation Bottom Tab?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have something like:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<DefaultTabbedParamList>();


const DefaultTabbedNavigation = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{
        unmountOnBlur: true,
      }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
          ...defaultOptions,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
            <Icon as={Ionicons} name={`home${focused ? `` : `-outline`}`} size={size} color={color} />
          )
        }} />
        ...
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}
```

When a user clicks to a detail view from `Home` (or any other tab), I want to load a detail view with the currently selected tab remaining.

What's the correct approach to handle this?

One idea I had was to have a `StackNavigator` in `HomeScreen` that includes a `Detail` screen. But it seems repetitive to do for every screen, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :-

```
 <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{
    unmountOnBlur: true,
  }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
      ...defaultOptions,
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => (
        <Icon as={Ionicons} name={`home${focused ? `` : `-outline`}`} size={size} color={color} />
      )
    }} />
    // Something like this.
    <Tab.Screen name="Home2" children={({route}) => <route?.name />} ...{otherProperties}/>
    ...
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

**Note:-** To use this kind of approch your routeName and componentName should be same.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                <Stack.Screen name={"Tabs"} component={Tabs} />
                <Stack.Screen name={"Detail"} component={DetailScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
```

Comment: The `Detail` won't have the tab bar at the bottom in this case though

Comment: hm... or ```<Detail>{children}</Detail>```?

Comment: ah i have good idea. declare state ```const [isDetail, setIsDetail] = useState(false)``` and ```if (isDetail) { return (<Detail>...</Detail>) } else { return (<Home>...</Home>) } ```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you'll likely want to define a `StackNavigator` for each tab. It's a bit repetitive, but that's been a theme of my experience with RN.

You can do something like:

```
const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const OtherStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Other" component={OtherScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const DefaultTabbedNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Other" component={OtherStackNavigator} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
   )
}
```